# Generic delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, delegates

I'm writing a small class which helps to fetch paged data automatically.

I have following delegate:

```
protocol DataAPIDelegate: class {
  func fetchItemsForPage<T>(api: DataAPI<T>, page: Int, onFinish: ([T] -> ())
}
```

And DataAPI class, which stores delegate:

```
class DataAPI<T> {
  weak var delegate: DataAPIDelegate? = nil

  //...
  //some other methods
}
```

Then, what I want to do is to write a view controller which uses DataAPI and communicates with this object by DataAPIDelegate:

```
class CarsViewController: DataAPIDelegate {
  var dataAPI = DataAPI<Car>

  // MARK :- DataAPIDelegate
  func fetchItemsForPage<T>(api: DataAPI<T>, page: Int, onFinish: ([T] -> ()) {
    let cars: [Car] = //some method for getting cars
    onFinish(cars)
  }
}
```

And I get the error: `Cannot invoke 'onFinish' with an argument list of type '([Car])'` in the line: `onFinish(cars)`.

I think about it for a few hours and I don't have any idea why it doesn't work. Anyone meets that problem?

Comment: Replace `T` with `Car` in your `CarsViewController` to fix compilation error. Check [this](http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/06/26/paging/) blog post about generic page generators, ...

Comment: After replacing `T` with `Car` i got the error: `'Car' is not identical to 'Car'` in the line with getting cars: `let car: [Car] = ...`. It seems like Swift compiler treats `Car` like a type variable (because of `fetchItemsForPage<Car>` declaration) and like a type itself (because of array assigned to `cars` variable), so it can't match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic functions provide single template implementation for multiple types referred by `T`, while what it seems you are trying to do is to provide an implementation of `fetchItemsForPage` method specifically for `Car` type.

The way it *would* work is:

```
protocol DataAPIDelegate: class {
    func fetchItemsForPage<T>(api: DataAPI<T>, page: Int, onFinish: ([T] -> ()))
}

class DataAPI<T> {
    weak var delegate: DataAPIDelegate? = nil

    //...
    //some other methods
}

struct Car { }

class CarsViewController: DataAPIDelegate {
    var dataAPI = DataAPI<Car>()

    // MARK :- DataAPIDelegate
    func fetchItemsForPage<T>(api: DataAPI<T>, page: Int, onFinish: ([T] -> ())) {
        let items: [T] = [T]()
        onFinish(items)
    }
}
```

... while what you are trying to do is:

```
struct Bike { }

class BikesViewController: DataAPIDelegate {
    var dataAPI = DataAPI<Bike>()

    // MARK :- DataAPIDelegate
    func fetchItemsForPage<Bike>(api: DataAPI<Bike>, page: Int, onFinish: ([Bike] -> ())) {
        let items: [Bike] = [Bike]()
        onFinish(items)
    }
}
```

... but in the latter snippet `Bike` is not a type but a placeholder, which works just the same as if you would use `T`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now. So what can I do in this situation? How `CarsViewController` can communicate with `DataAPI`?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Anton Bronnikov, quick question, how can I set delegate = self, if I cannot instantiate an object because it is a generic class which I don't have access to in the other class, yet I want the generics class to call a function in the other class, hence the need for delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Generic delegates aren't possible in Swift, if they aren't just functions. Because functions (closures) can be generic. See my gist where I tried to resolve the same problem: https://gist.github.com/artyom-razinov/fe8c2b7611a0ba3bd2a3